# Can an exception in a spring batch listener cause the job to fail?

Tags: listener, spring-batch

So two part question.

First, I recently encountered an error in a listener for a spring batch job. The job was processing 2000 records and successfully processed 1790 of them. The listener only processed about 100 records before it hit the exception and failed. There weren't any other exceptions in the job that got logged, aside from the same exception getting logged and preceded by

> 2018-01-10 15:21:24.798 ERROR 16416 --- [pool-5-thread-7] o.s.batch.core.job.AbstractJob           : Exception encountered in afterStep callback

Is it possible that the exception that killed the listener also stopped the job before it finished processing/committing the remaining 210 records? It doesn't seem to make a lot of sense, but I'm not sure what else could've resulted in those records not being committed.

Second, was what order does spring batch read in input files? The 210 records in the above scenario were the first 210 in the file. I was wondering if that's because spring batch reads in files from the last line to the first line which would explain why those were the records that didn't get processed.

Comment: Can you add more information (at least the rest of the stack trace)? The error you posted references the `afterStep`, but that implies processing ended prematurely BEFORE the `afterStep` would be executed.

Comment: @DeanClark I'll need a minute to dig it out, but it's just a null pointer exception in the java mail sender. Nothing fancy, and I know what caused it. I'm just not sure why not all the records processed. I would've expected that a listener wouldn't start until the job was completely finished.

Comment: You must be throwing something earlier to cause the step to end prematurely. Any other logging would be useful, or output from your `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION` table.

Comment: @DeanClark Don't know if this will help, but the exception shows up, then immediately afterward is that AbstractJob message followed by the exact same stack trace. The step record says it completed successfully.

Comment: Would just be speculating without more info

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the processing logic should also be written in Tasklet, ItemReader, ItemWriter, and ItemProcessor. Listeners should only be used if you want to do something before/After the step. Listeners should be used to pass the information between the steps or if you want to save the information or call the other system which is not part of batch to inform that the step is completed.

The Spring batch source code where the call to the listener is made. If you check the source code for `AbstracStep`

```js
try {
    // Update the step execution to the latest known value so the
    // listeners can act on it
    exitStatus = exitStatus.and(stepExecution.getExitStatus());
    stepExecution.setExitStatus(exitStatus);
    exitStatus = exitStatus.and(getCompositeListener().afterStep(stepExecution));
}
catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error(String.format("Exception in afterStep callback in step %s in job %s", name, stepExecution.getJobExecution().getJobInstance().getJobName()), e);
}
```

It is just catching the exception and moving on. Not sure, why it has been handled this way.

If you still want the spring batch to abort if something fails in the listener, all you need to do is catch the Exception in the listener and write the below code

```java
public class YourListener implements StepExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        try {
            yourcode ///////
        } catch (Exception e) {

            //log your error 
            stepExecution.setStatus(BatchStatus.FAILED);
            stepExecution.addFailureException(e);
            return ExistStatus.FAILED.addDescription(e);
        }
        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }
}
```

I know this is something weird/wrong way to do it. But if you don't catch your exception, Spring batch will do it for you and just log. It will move ahead without aborting/stopping the batch execution.